# Scrapy shell for a specific webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to launch scrapy shell for https://www.trekearth.com
after

```
scrapy shell https://www.trekearth.com
```

I recieve

```
2018-05-11 16:02:04 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying 
<GET https://www.trekearth.com> (failed 1 times): 524 Unknown Status
2018-05-11 16:02:05 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying 
<GET https://www.trekearth.com> (failed 2 times): 502 Bad Gateway
2018-05-11 16:03:45 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up 
retrying <GET https://www.trekearth.com> (failed 3 times): 524 Unknown Status
```

What is the reason for that? Every other website i have checked does not return comparable results.

Comment: Can you access TrekEarth with your favorite browser?

Comment: Yes i can with no difficulties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's some kind of a filter by user-agent:

```
scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36" https://www.trekearth.com
```

Comment: Works fine! Thank you very much!